# Ros hydro for ubuntu ARM and turtlebot

Tags: robotic-arm, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
I am installing the ros turltebot. I see in this website http://namniart.com/repos/status/hydro.html of libraries for ubuntu arm, it has ros-hydro-turtlebot-bringup or the other packages of turtlebot but when I typed command

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-turtlebot-bringup
```

I had the notice

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-turtlebot-bringup : Depends: ros-hydro-kobuki-bumper2pc but it is not installable
                               Depends: ros-hydro-kobuki-description but it is not installable
                               Depends: ros-hydro-kobuki-node but it is not installable
                               Depends: ros-hydro-kobuki-safety-controller but it is not installable
                               Depends: ros-hydro-openni-camera but it is not installable
                               Depends: ros-hydro-rocon-app-manager but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It means I have to install the below packages, but they are not supported in ros hydro for arm.
So what problem in here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114436/ros-hydro-for-ubuntu-arm-and-turtlebot/) by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known problem related to missing the Lisp interpreter on ARM.

I'm actively working on updated builds to fix this, but it requires patching the core ROS libraries and doing custom releases, so it's proceeding slowly. Hopefully I'll have something out by the end of the month.

In the meantime, you may be able to get around this by faking an installation of the `sbcl` package. It will be some work, but this looks like a good place to start; http://askubuntu.com/questions/18192/how-to-fake-a-package-version-installed

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2014-01-04**:
So in the future, ros hydro will suport enough features for turtlebot, such as cmd_vel_mux, kobuki_fdti... ?I think cmd_vel_mux is very important, if there is not this library, every one just work with turlesim, not real robot

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-20**:
At this point, I've resolved the lisp dependency and most of the base turtlebot and kobuki packages are building for ARM. The only thing that's still blocking installation of the turtlebot_bringup package is that kobuki_node depends on rviz, and rviz most definitely does not build on ARM.

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2014-01-21**:
That sounds good, thank you a lot.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2014-01-26**:
looks like this should be resolved by igloo

https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/issues/315
.